# MYSQL if a select query returns 0 rows then another select query?

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements, if-statement

if `select * from table where x=1` returns 0 rows, then I need `select * from table where x=2 [or some other query]`. Is it possible to do this in a single MySQL query with a conditional statement?

**Edit:**  All answers with `UNION` work, but only if both queries select from the same table (or tables with the same number of columns). What if the second query is applied on a different table with joins?

Let me write down the my queries to make the question more clear:

#### 1st:

```
SELECT  table1.a, table2.b  from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.x= table1.x
WHERE .....
```

if the result from the 1st one is null then:

#### 2nd:

```
SELECT table1.a FROM table1 
WHERE ....
```

I will be using the rows from the 1st query if it returns any, otherwise the 2nd one will be used.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this with a single MySQL query as opposed to using program logic and two separate queries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Another SELECT if the first SELECT returned an empty set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062313/another-select-if-the-first-select-returned-an-empty-set)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This appears to work from a quick test I just did and avoids the need to check for the existence of `x=1` twice.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM mytable
WHERE x = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE 
FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND x = 2;
```

Edit: Following your clarification to the question obviously the 2 queries will need to be UNION compatible for the above to work.

The answer to your updated question is No. This is not possible in a single query. You would need to use some [conditional procedural logic](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,33383,33383#msg-33383) to execute the desired query.

Comment: Thank you for that, Mr Smith. I didn't know about SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

Comment: the problem seems to be that `FOUND_ROWS()` will return a value for the next executed query, the `UNION ALL` considers both queries to be the same

Answer (score 1):

You could try...

```
SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE x = 1

UNION

SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE x = 2 AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                          FROM mytable
                          WHERE x = 1);
```

if you don't consider it too ghastly a hack.

Answer (score 0):

yes

Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

example :

```
SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2);
```

Comment: will this query return the rows from (SELECT * FROM t2) it any results EXIST(S)? because I will be needing them in that case...

Answer (score 0):

If the two queries return different number of columns, you can pad one of the results with empty columns and also add an identifier column first.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 1 query_type, mytable.*, 
'' col1, '' col2, '' col3, '' col4
FROM mytable
WHERE x = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 2, mytable2.*
FROM mytable2
WHERE 
FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND x = 2;
```

Where mytable2 has 4 more columns than mytable.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation is that:

```
SELECT IF(1 = 2,'true','false'); --> false
SELECT IF(1 = 1,' true','false'); --> true
SELECT IF(1 = 2,' true','false'), IF(1 = 1,' true','false'); --> false | true
```

The 'if' statement give some functionality to selected values.
The structure is something like this:

```
SELECT IF(<your statement>), ...<selected params>... FROM <your tables>
```

A great explanation can be found [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS` cannot be used in a single query, even if separate by `UNION` statements.

The correct way to do this would be:

```
WITH  my_cte AS
(
  SELECT * from original_set
)
SELECT * FROM my_cte
UNION ALL
SELECT opt.* FROM optional_set opt JOIN (SELECT count(*) v FROM my_cte) count ON count.v=0;
```

With the `JOIN` and the `UNION ALL` the performance of this query is almost equivalent to either of the individual standalone queries

Answer (score -1):

you can use EXIST and NOT EXIST statement to check that result is null or not. if result is Null then you can get value from table2.

Comment: And how is this an answer without showing SQL query?