# Another SELECT if the first SELECT returned an empty set

Tags: mysql, control-flow

This is my table:

```
  id    id_1     camp 
 1        0         x1     
 2        0         x2
 3        0         x3
 4        1         x4
 5        1         x5
 6        1         x6
 7        3         x7
 8        3         x8
 9        3         x9
```

I am in need of a SQL that, if there are no rows with `id_1` of "x", it should return those with `id_1` of 0. For example, if I were to select `id_1` = 2, it would return the `select * where`id_1`= 0`.

Could this be done in one statement? I had little luck using IF EXISTS or CASE. Syntax...

<kbd>Thanks, as always</kbd>

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If there are no rows with id_1 of "x", it should return those with id_1 of 0. You can try this -

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_1 = 2 ) 
    SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_1 = 2 
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_1 = 0
```

Comment: That didn't work for some reason. But this did:
`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id_1 = IF(EXISTS(SELECT id_1 FROM myTable WHERE id_1 = 2 LIMIT 1), 2, 0)`. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it using sql server before posting. But, I the syntax is different for mysql.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, id_1, camp
FROM your_table
WHERE id_1 = 2

UNION ALL

SELECT id, id_1, camp
FROM your_table
WHERE 
FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND id_1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE id_1 = 2 
UNION ALL
  SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE id_1 = 0 
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT * 
          FROM mytable 
          WHERE id_1 = 2
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't ignore a way to implement this logic in your code instead of SQL.