# Can I do that in the SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say I have a post table. But I want to query all today post. But if today post is less than 10 post, I will get back the yesterday post to query. If it is more than 10 posts, no need to query yesterday post....If SQL statement can't do it. Is this only achieve it by calling the post manually....? Thank you.

***The database is MySQL

Let me clarify the question in a typical example:

> If today have 5 posts....ONLY. And yesterday have 10 posts.
>
> return : 5 today posts, and 5 posts from yesterday

```
If today have 12 posts....ONLY.
And yesterday have 10 posts. 

return : 12 today posts.
```

> If today have 10 posts....ONLY. And yesterday have 10 posts.
>
> return : 10 today posts.

```
If today have 2 posts....ONLY. yesterday have 5 posts, and the day before yesterday 5posts. 

return : 2 today posts, 5 yesterday posts, 3 the day before yesterday posts.
```

Comment: You need to get 10 most recent posts, regardless if they are made today or yesterday, am I right?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Also if today has 9 posts and yesterday 100 you want to bring back 109 in total or just the top 10? And if today has 60 posts it should bring them all back?

Comment: @DiagonalBatman - Please let the OP clarify the requirement. Don't make an edit that actually changes the meaning of the question.

Comment: To all, I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: You still haven't stated RDBMS

Comment: Agree with Martin.  If you can't understand the requirement in the question, don't edit the question to make the requirement simpler.  Ask for clarification.

Comment: sorry, I updated. I use MySQL....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
select count(*) from post_table
where date = todays_date
```

and if the result is > 10 then

```
select * from post_table
where date = today's date
```

else

```
select * from post_table  
order by date desc
limit 10
```

Answer (score 2):

A tiny development on [Jan S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400863/can-i-do-that-in-the-sql-statement/7400909#7400909)'s solution (combines the two conditional SELECTs into one with a parametrised LIMIT):

```
SELECT @count := COUNT(*)
FROM post_table
WHERE date = today;

IF @count < 10 SET @count = 10;

SELECT *
FROM post_table
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT @count;
```

---

**UPDATE**

As stated in the documentation:

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using `?` placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

That means, you can only use code like above in a stored procedure, not in a plain query you are issuing in your client application.

Comment: If you can parameterise `limit` then might be possible to do something with a `UNION ALL` and a `CASE` expression involving `FOUND_ROWS` [as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202242/mysql-if-a-select-query-returns-0-rows-then-another-select-query/3202368#3202368)? Don't have MySQL installed at the mo to test.

Comment: *‘Thank you for that, Mr Smith. I didn't know about FOUND_ROWS()’* – that's what Mr Brian Hooper might say on the occasion. And if he did say that, I would probably say then: *‘I didn't either. Thank you, Mr Smith.’*. The level of LIMIT's parametrisability is [quite poor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html#id957441) at the moment, being a [recent addition](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918) too. In short, you can't put an expression after LIMIT, only a variable. Something like `UNION SELECT @count = 10 - FOUND_ROWS(), … WHERE @count > 0 LIMIT @count` *might* do, though...

Answer (score 2):

Just another idea, a little bit shorter:

```
set @i = 0;
select *, @i := @i + 1
from post_table
where @i < 10 or date = today
order by date desc;
```

Not sure it is very effective.

Update: it is fast!
I tested on the such sample:

```
create table a(i int primary key, d date not null, index idx(d)) 
set @i = 0;

insert into a(i, d)
select @i := @i + 1, adddate(curdate(), interval -(@i % 1000) day) 
from <100 records> a, <100 records> b, <100 records> c
```

Comment: +1 This does only access the table once. Question is will it stop scanning as soon as the `@i < 10` is reached? I'd add a condition `and date <= yesterday` just in case.