# MYSQL if @@ROWCOUNT UNION SELECT ANOTHER QUERY

Tags: mysql, union

The following is a query from SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE item.name = hank
If @@ROWCOUNT < 20 THEN
UNION
SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE item.name = jim
ENDIF
```

Is this possible in MySQL?

Comment: Is your intention to write a stored procedure?

Comment: [The `IF` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) you are using (which is not [the `IF` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if_)) only works in stored procedures.

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` is SQL Server-specific so I've edited your question with what I'm guessing is accurate. Feel free to clarify things further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you don't need `union` for that.  One option would be to use `order by` with `limit`:

```
select * 
from item
where name in ('hank','jim')
order by name
limit 20
```

This will select 20 rows from the `item` table, starting with those rows where `name = 'hank'`.  You could also consider using:

```
order by case when name = 'hank' then 0 else 1 end 
limit 20
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6c49/1) (change the limit to see)

Comment: This is not really what I'm looking for. My actual query is unbelievably complicated, so this will not work for me. What is really need, is just a simple solution for seeing if the row count is more than 10, and then union select a second query

Comment: @DrivingInsanee -- if you want to include if logic in your sql, you're going to need to create a stored procedure.  Here's a slightly different take on the posted solution which might help (based on same concept though): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6c49/4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this behaviour is documented/guaranteed but [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3202368/73226) I found the following worked.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM Item
WHERE Name ='Hank'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Item
WHERE FOUND_ROWS() < 20 AND Name = 'Jim';
```