# Put IF in Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

How can this code convert to correct query? Is it possible?

First I want check if `id IN (55,1454,232,444,10999,223)` is exists rows. Second if not exists get rows by random.

```
 SELECT
      id
      name
      title
 FROM
      table t
 WHERE
      id IN (55,1454,232,444,10999,223)

 IF count_row(t) == 0 // <-- if for WHERE no result row
      SELECT
           id
           name
           title
      FROM
           table
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Do you use something like php ? Also I don't think you can do both in MySqli you should rather do that in 2 queries like "1 -> Select from where and 2 -> if row_count(old_query) = 0, do the other query".

Comment: You can make `stored procedure ` for this

Comment: @Pleasure yes `php`, Exactly I do not want use 2 query. is it possible one query?

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad what is `stored procedure`?

Comment: @grizzly check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202242/mysql-if-a-select-query-returns-0-rows-then-another-select-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like :

```
   SELECT id,
          name,
          title
    FROM
          table t
    WHERE
          id IN (55,1454,232,444,10999,223)

    UNION

    SELECT *
    FROM
        table t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id,
                             name,
                             title
                      FROM
                             table t
                      WHERE
                             id IN (55,1454,232,444,10999,223));
```

Comment: Honestly, not sure with MySqli because I never used it but if you're using php, both are fine. I'll rather go for the 2 queries because its more "versatile". For example you could want to add another query if it only returns one line. It also depends on the number of lines you have in your table t. Can't really ask, try both and see who's the best (fastest ?)

Comment: @grizzly No problem !