# How to run alternative where condition if row is zero

Tags: mysql

Suppose i have a table

**table**

```
+-------------+
| id  |  name |
+-------------+
|  1  |  xabx |
|  2  |  abxd |
|  3  |  axcd |
|  4  |  azyx |
|  5  |  atyl |
|  6  |  aksd |
|  7  |  baabc|
|  8  |  aabcd|
+-------------+
```

first i have to get data if matches first some char like :

if `name = aab`

then have to run `select * from table where name like 'aab%'`

then it returns

```
+-------------+
|  8  | aabcd |
+-------------+
```

which execatlly i want

but if i have only `abc`

then the above query return `0` row

then i have to search from middle like :

`select * from table where name like '%abc%'`

then it returns which is the alternative

```
+-------------+
|  7  |  baabc|
|  8  |  aabcd|
+-------------+
```

i have no much knowledge about mysql is there any query which can do like if first where condition don't have row then run alternative where condition

i have tried this but didn't work as i want.

`select * from table where name like 'abc%' or name like '%abc%'`

[fiddle](http://rextester.com/TSNP34347)

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use `%match%` every time?

Comment: What is wrong in the output of your last query?

Comment: table name is missing.

Comment: You also said "form" not "from" in your last query.

Comment: @Aknosis there n number of record this might help if person get easily what he is looking for. for example there is two record has common char like `bhaab` and `aabcd`  and he want 'aabcd' search `aab` then it return `bhaab`first.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3202368/73226

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat your desired result:

```
select *from t
where (case
           when name like 'abc' then 1
           when name like 'bc%' then 1
           when name like '%bc' then 1   
           when name like '%bc%' then 1     
           else null
           end)  
order by name
  limit 1;
```

I just put all the combinations as conditions.
You can interchange their sequence or remove unnecessary condition.
`limit 1` makes only 1 row visible for whichever condition satisfies.

Here is the answer from your fiddle. [Check it out](http://rextester.com/MAN24628)

Hope it helps!

Comment: If the above answer solved/helped to solve your problem then kindly accept it as answer and/or upvote the answer. That'll be really helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

Left joining the table on itself, where the table is initially filtered by the more inclusive `%bx%` and then the join is filtered by the more restrictive `bx%`.

This allows you to use the joined name if it exists, but revert to the original if not:

```
SELECT t1.id, IF(t2.name IS NULL, t1.name, t2.name) name
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id = t1.id AND t1.name like 'bx%'
WHERE t1.name LIKE '%bx%'
```

This may/may not be ideal depending on the size or your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` checking may work

```
select * 
from table 
where name like 'aab%' or 
      ((select count(*) from table where name like 'aab%') = 0 and name like '%abc%')
```

I guess that it would be a good idea to compute the count value into a variable first, however, the optimizer may recognize independent subquery anyway and run it once.